# Multiple query results to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a function that loops through a list of DB tables and returns the table name and count in a dataframe

```
d = {}      
    for table in tables:
        a.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM {}'.format(table))
        for row in a.fetchall():
            key = table
            val = row[0]
            d[key] = val
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['Source_Table', 'Source_Cnt'])
```

This works fine, but I want to modify the select statement so it looks like this and returns 1 row with 2 column results:

```
'SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    MAX(COALESCE(MODIFY_DT, CREATE_DT)) AS LAST_MODIFIED
FROM {}'.format(table)
```

Then I would store it in the dataframe as Source_Table, Source_Cnt, Source_Max_Date

When I try to just add a column name to the dataframe it doesn't work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['Source_Table', 'Source_Cnt', 'Src_Max_Date'])

AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns
```

I think it's the way I am storing the key, val in d{}. It's not allowing for > 1 column, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

d.items() returns a list like below.

[(key,(values)),...]

eg:-

```
>>> d={'A':[1,2],'B':[3,4]}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('A', [1, 2]), ('B', [3, 4])])
```

So it has only two columns. That's why it returns a error.